# What does this parser error mean and how can it be fixed? 

Tags: grub2, plymouth, burg

Well, I messed up everything and was forced to remove and re-install the system. Everything is fixed now, but for the sake of knowledge, I want to know what this error means exactly. It shows up after booting Ubuntu (instead of the Plymouth boot screen). How it can be fixed?

`parser error: error opening file /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphical boot only occurs if you pass the `splash` boot option for the kernel.  Did you remember to include that option when configuring the new boot loader?

The default Ubuntu configuration also uses the `quiet` boot option to suppress informational messages during boot.  If you want things to be as close to the standard boot sequence as possible, make sure you are including it too.

Comment: I've followed the instructions in http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/beautiful-burg-boot-loader-gets-ubuntu-11-04-ppa/ , and did exactly the same. But I remember that a screen showed up when I installed burg , but I didn't know what to do.

Comment: So does your Burg configuration file include the `quiet splash` arguments for the configured kernel you're booting?  The configuration file you're looking for will probably be somewhere under `/boot` rather than `/etc`.

Comment: In `/boot/grub` , I found `grub.cfg` 

In `/boot/burg` , I found `burg.cfg`  

What to do now ?

Comment: @binarylife Put all this new information in your question, that way it gets a bump and we know right up front as you try to debug your problem, otherwise it gets buried in the comments!

Comment: @Jorge Castro going to , I've lost plymouth at all